# How do you collect trigonometric functions in a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

I have an expression that has various forms of Sin and Cos and I want to collect them specifically so that I can make substitutions.

As you can see I cannot figure out how to separate i Cos[theta] from Cos[theta] each other

```
ur= ur4= -B3 Cos[θ] + B5 Cos[θ] - B4 θ Cos[θ] + 
 B6 θ Cos[θ] - (
 2 I B4 EI GA Cos[θ])/Φ - (
2 I B6 EI GA Cos[θ])/Φ - I B3 Sin[θ] - 
I B5 Sin[θ] - I B4 θ Sin[θ] - 
I B6 θ Sin[θ] + (
2 B4 EI GA Sin[θ])/Φ - (
 2 B6 EI GA Sin[θ])/Φ


Collect[ur4, {Cos[θ], I Cos[θ], θ Cos[θ], 
  Sin[θ], 
  I Sin[θ], θ Sin[θ]}] /. {-B4 + 
   B6 -> -C5} /. {-I B4 - I B6 -> C6} /. {B4 - B6 -> 
C5} /. {B4 I + B6I -> -C6}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sin you don't have a `Sin[x]Cos[x]` term, you can use `Coefficient`

```
Coefficient[ur, Cos[θ];
ComplexExpand[%]
Coefficient[ur, Sin[θ];
ComplexExpand[%]
```

> $\left.\text{-B3+B5-B4 $\theta $+B6 $\theta $+i (-}\frac{2\ \text{B4}\
>    \text{EI}\ \text{GA}}{\Phi }-\frac{2\ \text{B6}\
>    \text{EI}\ \text{GA}}{\Phi }\right)$
>
> $\text{i (-B3-B5-B4 $\theta $-B6 $\theta $)+}\frac{2\ \text{B4}\
>    \text{EI}\ \text{GA}}{\Phi }-\frac{2\ \text{B6}\
>    \text{EI}\ \text{GA}}{\Phi }$